# IMFTransform::ProcessOutput returns E_INVALIDARG

Tags: c, audio, ms-media-foundation

## The problem

I am trying to get call `ProcessOutput` to get decoded data from my decoder and get the following error:

> `E_INVALIDARG` One or more arguments are invalid.

## What I have tried

As `ProcessOutput` has many arguments I have tried to pinpoint what the error might be. [Documentation for `ProcessOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704014(v=vs.85).aspx) does not mention `E_INVALIDARG`. However, the [documentation for `MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697247(v=vs.85).aspx), the datatype for one of the arguments, mentions in its Remarks section that:

> Any other combinations are invalid and cause `ProcessOutput` to return `E_INVALIDARG`

What it talks about there is how the `MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER` struct is setup. So an incorrectly setup `MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER` might cause that error. I have however tried to set it up correctly.

By calling GetOutputStreamInfo I find that I need to allocate the sample sent to ProcessOutput which is what I do. I'm using pretty much the same method that worked for ProcessInput so I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

I have also tried to make sure that the other arguments, who logically should also be able to cause an `E_INVALIDARG`. They look good to me and I have not been able to find any other leads to which of my arguments to `ProcessOutput` might be invalid.

## The code

I have tried to post only the relevant parts of the code below. I have removed or shortened many of the error checks for brevity. Note that I am using plain C.

#### "Prelude"

```c
...
hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->SetOutputType(pDecoder, dwOutputStreamID, pMediaOut, dwFlags);
...
// Send input to decoder
hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->ProcessInput(pDecoder, dwInputStreamID, pSample, dwFlags);
if (FAILED(hr)) { /* did not fail */ }
```

So before the interesting code below I have successfully setup things (I hope) and sent them to ProcessInput which did not fail. I have 1 input stream and 1 output stream, AAC in, PCM out.

#### Code directly leading to the error

```c
// Input has now been sent to the decoder
// To extract a sample from the decoder we need to create a strucure to hold the output
// First we ask the OutputStream for what type of output sample it will produce and who should allocate it
// Then we create both the sample in question (if we should allocate it that is) and the MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER
// which holds the sample and some other information that the decoder will fill in.

#define SAMPLES_PER_BUFFER 1 // hardcoded here, should depend on GetStreamIDs results, which right now is 1

MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER pOutputSamples[SAMPLES_PER_BUFFER];
DWORD *pdwStatus = NULL;

// There are different allocation models, find out which one is required here.
MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO streamInfo = { 0,0,0 };
MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_INFO *pStreamInfo = &streamInfo;

hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->GetOutputStreamInfo(pDecoder, dwOutputStreamID, pStreamInfo);
if (FAILED(hr)) { ... }

if (pStreamInfo->dwFlags == MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_PROVIDES_SAMPLES) { ... }
else if (pStreamInfo->dwFlags == MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_CAN_PROVIDE_SAMPLES) { ... }
else {  
    // default, the client must allocate the output samples for the stream
    IMFSample *pOutSample = NULL;
    DWORD minimumSizeOfBuffer = pStreamInfo->cbSize;
    IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;

    // CreateMediaSample is explained further down. 
    hr = CreateMediaSample(minimumSizeOfBuffer, sampleDuration, &pBuffer, &pOutSample);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            BGLOG_ERROR("error");
        }

    pOutputSamples[0].pSample = pOutSample;
}

// since GetStreamIDs return E_NOTIMPL then dwStreamID does not matter
// but its recomended that it is set to the array index, 0 in this case.
// dwOutputStreamID will be 0 when E_NOTIMPL is returned by GetStremIDs
pOutputSamples[0].dwStreamID = dwOutputStreamID; // = 0
pOutputSamples[0].dwStatus = 0;
pOutputSamples[0].pEvents = NULL; // have tried init this myself, but MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER documentation says not to.

hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->ProcessOutput(pDecoder, dwFlags, outputStreamCount, pOutputSamples, pdwStatus);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    // here E_INVALIDARG is found.
}
```

CreateMediaSample that is used in the code is derived from [an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530106(v=vs.85).aspx) from the official documentation but modified to call SetSampleDuration and SetSampleTime. I get the same error by not setting those two though so it should be something else causing the problem.

#### Some of the actual data that was sent to ProcessOutput

In case I might have missed something which is easy to see from the actual data:

```
hr = pDecoder->lpVtbl->ProcessOutput(
    pDecoder, // my decoder
    dwFlags, // 0
    outputStreamCount, // 1 (from GetStreamCount)
    pOutputSamples, // se comment below
    pdwStatus // NULL
);
// pOutputSamples[0] holds this struct:
// dwStreamID = 0, 
// pSample = SampleDefinedBelow 
// dwStatus = 0, 
// pEvents = NULL

// SampleDefinedBelow:
// time = 0
// duration = 0.9523..
// buffer = with max length set correctly 
// attributes[] = NULL
```

## Question

So anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong or how I could debug this further?

Comment: At least, `pdwStatus` thing is not okay. You should have `DWORD dwStatus` variable and `&dwStatus` as the argument.

Comment: @Alex Telon Try to ZeroMemory the pOutputSamples prior to pOutputSamples[0].pSample = pOutSample; call. Have you also checked if the value of pStreamInfo->cbSize is not 0?

Comment: @RomanR. yes, thanks an obvious error now that you mention it!

I no longer get the E_INVALIDARG error but now a E_FAIL which I have to dig into. But your answer solved the problem. If you add it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks @VuVirt Though Roman's answer fixed the issue, I tried what you suggested in case I had missed something more. I tried `ZeroMemory(pOutputSamples, sizeof(MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER))`, but no change in behaviour. 
pStreamInfo->cbSize is `0x0000c000`, dwFlags is `MFT_OUTPUT_STREAM_WHOLE_SAMPLES` and cbAlignment is `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProcessOutput` needs a valid pointer as the last argument, so this does not work:

```
DWORD *pdwStatus = NULL;
pDecoder->lpVtbl->ProcessOutput(..., pdwStatus);
```

This is okay:

```
DWORD dwStatus;
pDecoder->lpVtbl->ProcessOutput(..., &dwStatus);
```

Regarding further `E_FAIL` - your findings above, in general, looks good. It is not that I see something obvious, and also the error code does not suggest that the problem is with MFT data flow. Perhaps it could be bad data or data not matching media types set.